# Java файл не запускается в cmd если в нем содержится package

Tags: java

Есть такой код на Java:

```
package helloww;

public class Hworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Worldik!");
    }

}
```

Если в командной строке делать компиляцию (javac Hworld.java), то все успешно (файл `Hworld.class` создан). А если пробовать запустить (java Hworld), то ошибка.

Все дело как я понял в пакете, т.к. если стереть строку `package helloww;` то программа успешно запускается (выводит: Hello Worldik!).

Как делать так, чтобы файл запустился с пакетом `package helloww;` ?

Comment: `java helloww.Hworld`?

Comment: java -cp . helloww.Hworld

Answer (score 1):

1. В собранном jar должен быть файл манифеста - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

В нем должен быть определен

```
Main-Class: helloww.Hworld
```

Тогда вы сможете его запустить как `java -jar MyJar.jar`

2. Собранный пакет указываете в Class Path

   java -cp MyJar.jar helloww.Hworld

Тогда java просканирует jar и запустит класс.

3. Если собраны только классы, то тогда следует соблюдать пути каталогов по простому правилу - имя пакета = имени каталога относительно того каталога в котором выполняться команда `java helloww.Hworld`

т.е.

```
. //тут я нахожусь во время запуска комнады
|
+-+ helloww //Дочерний каталог
  |
  +---- Hworld.class //Скомпилированный класс
```

В этом случае прежде чем продолжать настоятельно рекомендую прочитать [учебник](http://www.proklondike.com/books/java/yakov_fine_java4kids.html).

Comment: до jarников тут еще не дошли похоже. тут более простой пример.